# Qual a diferença entre o ngOnInit e o Constructor

Tags: angular

O problema que eu me deparei foi o seguinte: Precisava validar um token quando a pagina fosse iniciada se o token fosse valido então ficaria visível um segundo forms se não apenas o primeiro forms onde eu chamaria essa função? no `ngOnInit` ou no `constructor`?

Se o angular já fornece o `ngOnInit` pq há também um `constructor`?

Quando devo usar o `ngOnInit` ou o `constructor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O problema que eu me deparei foi o seguinte: Precisava validar um
>   token quando a pagina fosse iniciada se o token fosse valido então
>   ficaria visível um segundo forms se não apenas o primeiro forms onde
>   eu chamaria essa função? no ngOnInit ou no constructor?

No `ngOnInit`, pois ele pode ser usado justamente pra esse tipo de coisa, evitar lógica no construtor.

> Se o angular já fornece o ngOnInit pq há também um constructor?

São duas coisas com propósitos diferentes:

O `constructor` é o método default da classe. No Angular ele é usado principalmente para injetar dependências no componente

O `ngOnInit` faz parte do ciclo de vida do componente. Uma prática comum é usar ele para inicialização da lógica do componente.

> Quando devo usar o ngOnInit ou o constructor?

Normalmente os dois são usados juntos, pois cada um tem um propósito diferente, como dito anteriormente.

[Artigo interessante que fala um pouco sobre](https://indepth.dev/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular#difference-related-to-the-component-initialization-process--2/)